# How to solve this linear equation?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+4y=x^{2}e^{2x}$

how to solve this. this is linear equation.
what type of equation is it? first order?

Comment: I think you have mixed the dependent and independent variables in the early part of the ode. can you check again the book? I think it should be $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Indeed... the equation as it stands is non-grammatical:  $({dy \over dx})^2$ makes no sense.

Comment: this is y-double prime. i mean 2nd time derivative...

Comment: To avoid ambiguity, please write your equation in Mathematica format.

Comment: Just type `eq = y''[x] + 6 y'[x] + 4 y[x] == x^2* Exp[2 x]; DSolve[eq, y[x], x]` and you'll get the solution. it is linear second oder ODE.

Comment: Is this really $\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$ or $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$?

Answer (score 0):

you can find the solutions of the homogeneous equation $$y'' + 6y' + 4y = 0 $$ by trying solutions of the form $y = e^{kx}.$ we need $k$ to satisfy the characteristic equation $$k^2 + 6k + 4 = 0 \to (k+3)^2 = 5 \to k = -3 \pm \sqrt 5$$  therefore two independent solutions are $$e^{(3+\sqrt 5)x}, e^{(3-\sqrt 5)x}$$

to find a particular solution to  $$y'' + 6y' + 4y = x^2e^{2x} \tag 1$$ you can go with the method of undetermined coefficients by looking for a solution in the form $$y = e^{2x}\left(ax^2 + bx + c\right)$$ sub $y$ in $(1)$ and find the constants $a, b, c.$

Comment: i don't understand. will u finish the math please??